# I get the error "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" when I read the file

Tags: python, text-files

I'm working on a project that can code and decode a input using text files. In the part where it decodes it give an error and I don't know why. If you google it, you get results where the problem is in the path. But I don't have a path. What can I do? The error is in the line 62. This is the whole code. That's the second line in the loop 'while i < lengte + 1'. I am dutch so if the names of variables don't always make sense that's why. the full error is

```
    readed = compressed.read(i)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument'
```

```
message = input("what's your input?")
lengte = len(message)

compressed = open('compressed message.txt', 'a')
compressed.truncate(0)
compressed.close()

codeBook = {}

i = 0

text = message[i]
codeBook[text] = 1
eersteLetter = text + " " 
compressed = open('compressed message.txt', 'a')
compressed.write(eersteLetter)
compressed.close()
i += 1

while i < lengte :
    text = message[i]
    while text in codeBook:
        if i < lengte-1: 
            text = text + message[i+1]
        i += 1
if len(text) > 2:
    duplicate = text[0:-2]
    compressedText = str(codeBook[duplicate]) + text[-1]
    compressed = open('compressed message.txt', 'a')
    compressed.write(compressedText)
    codeBook[text] = len(codeBook)+1
    compressed.close()
elif len(text) > 1:
    duplicate = text[0]
    compressedText = str(codeBook[duplicate]) + text[-1]
    compressed.write(compressedText)
    codeBook[text] = len(codeBook)+1
    compressed.close()
else:
    compressedText = text
    compressed = open('compressed message.txt', 'a')
    compressed.write(compressedText)
    codeBook[text] = len(codeBook)+1
    compressed.close
    i += 1

compressed = open('compressed message.txt', 'r')
print(compressed.read())
compressed.close()
print(codeBook)



bookCode = {}
i = 1
compressed = open('compressed message.txt', 'r')
lengte = len(compressed.read())
compressed.close()

while i < lengte+1:
    compressed = open('compressed message.txt', 'r')
    readed = compressed.read(i)
    compressed.close()
    if readed == ' ':
        i += 1
    elif type(readed) == int:
        i += 1
        compressed = open('compressed message.txt', 'r')
        text = text + bookCode[readed] + compressed.read(i)
        bookCode[len(bookCode)+1] = bookCode[readed] + compressed.read(i)
        compressed.close()
        i += 1
    elif type(readed) == str:
        text = text + readed
        bookCode[len(bookCode)+1] = readed
print(' ')
print(text)
print(bookCode)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full text of the error traceback you get when you try to run the code.

Comment: I think I have done it

Answer (score 0):

if the path of this txt file is in the current locations it must work but if not you should find the full path and store it  in an variable . Like path= “C://Desktop// and more

Comment: the path of the txt file is in the current location